# How can i be able to import product with images to a store in big commerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have used .csv file to import products in BigCommerce.Everything is imported correctly except the images, although I have provided the image URL in the .csv file.Can somebody help me out in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

This BigCommerce support article has good info:
https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Importing-Exporting-Products#import-images

A couple very important highlights:

1. In WebDAV, use this folder: /dav/product_images/import
2. WebDAV is case-sensitive, so make sure that your file names (including the extension) match those in the import folder. Characters are restricted to a-z, 0-9, - and _.